# Magento how to get all the parents of current category?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I was just trying to find a code that can get current category and all the parent categories, also if there is a way to get the level of the categories to have a control over them.
I have a code but it gets only the parent of the current category:

```
<?php
    $currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');
    if ( $currentCat->getParentId() == Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() )
    {
        // current category is a toplevel category
        $loadCategory = $currentCat;
    } else {
        // current category is a sub-(or subsub-, etc...)category of a toplevel category
        // load the parent category of the current category
        $loadCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCat->getParentId());
    }
    $subCategories = explode(',', $loadCategory->getChildren());
    foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId )    
    {
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);
        if($cat->getIsActive())
        {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a style="color:green" href="'.$cat->getURL().'">';            
            echo $cat->getName();
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }

?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

let's say that `$category` is your current category.
You can call `$category->getParentCategories()` and you will get an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection`.
You can loop through it and get each category in the tree branch.
You should be able to call `->getLevel()` on each of these categories to see how high or low they are in the tree.

**[EDIT]**
You can do this to loop through all the parent categories

```
foreach ($category->getParentCategories() as $parent) {
    //do something with $parent.
    if ($parent->getLevel() == 2) {
        //then $parent is a top level category
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi can you please give a bit more info I am all dazed here.

Comment: See my edit. I'm not sure what more you need.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i need the thing is i need to keep the level printed even if its the next one. Like this page basically i need a drop down search like this: http://www.allbatteries.co.uk/battery/car-battery.html

Comment: Ok ok sounds like i asked way too much. Just tell me how to make this work for the moment its not getting anything: if ($parent->getLevel() == 3) {
                    echo $category->getName();
                }

Answer (score 2):

Given current category:

```
$currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');
```

You can get all parent ids by the *path*, which is in the form `1/2/3/4`, where in this example 1 is the system root category (this is actually always 1), 4 the current category 3 the immediate parent and 2 the second parent (the root category of the *store*)

```
$parentIds = explode('/', $currentCat->getPath());
array_pop($parentIds);
array_shift($parentIds);
```

Now `$parentIds` is an array with `[2,3]`.

Comment: If you want to load the categories and not include the store root category, please refer to @Marius answer instead.

Comment: Your's and Marius's answers are great but i need to get category names urls too.

Comment: When you loop (foreach) over `$category->getParentCategories()`, you should be able to use `getName()` and `getUrl()` on them

Comment: Alright the Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 7 ), printing nicely but (foreach) crashing the page.

Comment: I was refering to Marius' answer ;) Mine only gives you the ids, which you could use to filter a category collection but using getParentCategories() is more straightforward and you should do it

Answer (score 0):

Replace your first line:

```
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
```

With

```
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$category = checkCategoryLevel($category);
function checkCategoryLevel($category) {
    if( $category->getLevel() == 2) {
        foreach ($category->getParentCategories() as $parent) {
            if( $category->getId() != $parent->getId()) {
                return Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parent->getId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If it works, place "checkCategoryLevel($category)" somewhere in block file.